# How to apply texture to custom made object

Tags: texturing

I have a texture here that I am using:
[image]

And I am trying to apply it to a curved surface:

[image]

However the texture is not applied correctly. If I were to apply it to a generic shape like a cylinder or cube however, it works.

What can I do to fix the texture on my custom surface?

Comment: Have you applied the scale (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) to your object and UV unwrapped it?